# How to set local domain as a redirect address for OAuth?

Tags: oauth, localhost, google-plus, google-oauth

I am developing OAuth through Google at my local machine, where I've set up a fake domain 1cr.dev. So when creating credentials for API keys, I need to give an allowed redirect URL. But Google doesn't let me use a fictional domain, it says that the first-level domain needs to be public.

How can I get through that protection and set the URL I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "1cr.dev", make it look more realistic, eg. "mydevpc.example.com". The just add an entry in your /etc/hosts (or windoze equivalent) that resolves to 127.0.0.1, eg

`127.0.0.1           localhost, mydevpc.example.com`

Comment: Thanks :) too bad it's the only solution here... Or maybe I can just associate that dev.example.com with 1cr.dev in my /etc/hosts?